# static_new and static_delete

Tags: c++, c++11

Here's a trick for preallocating some memory for some type `T`. Do there exist similar tricks? Improvements?

```
#include <cassert>

#include <cstdlib>

#include <atomic>

#include <limits>

#include <new>

#include <thread>

#include <utility>

namespace
{
  template <typename T, typename A = unsigned>
  struct static_store
  {
    static constexpr auto const max_instances =
      ::std::numeric_limits<unsigned char>::digits * sizeof(A);

    static void cleanup() { delete [] store_; }

#ifdef __GNUC__
    template <typename U>
    static int ffz(U const v)
    {
      return __builtin_ctzll(~v);
    }
#elif _MSC_VER && !__INTEL_COMPILER
    template <typename U>
    static int ffz(U const v)
    {
      return ::std::numeric_limits<unsigned char>::digits * sizeof(v) -
        __lzcnt64(v & -v);
    }
#elif __INTEL_COMPILER
    template <typename U>
    static int ffz(U const v)
    {
      return _bit_scan_forward(~v);
    }
#else
    template <typename U>
    static int ffz(U v)
    {
      decltype(ffz()) b{};

      for (; (v & 1); ++b)
      {
        v >>= 1;
      }

      return b;
    }
#endif

    static ::std::atomic_flag lock_;

    static A memory_map_;

    static typename ::std::aligned_storage<sizeof(T),
      alignof(T)>::type* store_;
  };

  template <typename T, typename A>
  ::std::atomic_flag static_store<T, A>::lock_;

  template <typename T, typename A>
  A static_store<T, A>::memory_map_;

  template <typename T, typename A>
  typename ::std::aligned_storage<sizeof(T), alignof(T)>::type*
    static_store<T, A>::store_{(::std::atexit(static_store<T, A>::cleanup),
      new typename ::std::aligned_storage<sizeof(T),
        alignof(T)>::type[static_store<T, A>::max_instances])};

  template <typename T, typename ...A>
  inline T* static_new(A&& ...args)
  {
    using static_store = static_store<T>;

    while (static_store::lock_.test_and_set(::std::memory_order_acquire))
    {
      ::std::this_thread::yield();
    }

    auto const i(static_store::ffz(static_store::memory_map_));

    auto p(new (&static_store::store_[i]) T(::std::forward<A>(args)...));

    static_store::memory_map_ |= 1ull << i;

    static_store::lock_.clear(::std::memory_order_release);

    return p;
  }

  template <typename T>
  inline void static_delete(T* const p)
  {
    using static_store = static_store<T>;

    auto const i(p - static_cast<T*>(static_cast<void*>(
      static_store::store_)));
    //assert(!as_const(static_store::memory_map_)[i]);

    while (static_store::lock_.test_and_set(::std::memory_order_acquire))
    {
      ::std::this_thread::yield();
    }

    static_store::memory_map_ &= ~(1ull << i);

    static_cast<T*>(static_cast<void*>(&static_store::store_[i]))->~T();

    static_store::lock_.clear(::std::memory_order_release);
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
auto const p(static_new<int>());
*p = 10;
static_delete(p);
```

The code uses an integral type (`A`), as a bit mask, where each cleared bit means, that a corresponding slot in the `store_` is not occupied, and a set bit means it is occupied. This is done to minimize the storage requirements for the allocation mechanism. To find a free slot, the `ffz` function (find first zero) is used: it is compiled into a single instruction on many platforms. The same thing could have been done with an array of `bool`s, but with greatly increased storage requirements.

Comment: Let teh editz commence? ;-)

Comment: @Jamal nay, let the comments begin!

Comment: That, too.  But what about the answers?

Comment: @Jamal Hmmm, that too, I hope especially for alternative trickery, that one might use.

Comment: If you have tricks. Ask on stackoverflow. There are many more experienced C++ users there that can tell you if it is a good idea or not.

Comment: @LokiAstari That's their problem. They are so elite, they tear down every new idea, while my motto is: "if you like it and it works, then why not use it".

Comment: @user1095108: They will tear it down if it is a bad idea. If you can defend it then they will accept it. But I am unsure why I need it? Why would i use this over normal new? Also I find it hard to follow your code. But just a quick glance reveals problems that I could tear it apart with. But what I really want to know is what is the use case where this is useful.

Comment: @LokiAstari When you need memory from the heap, without the overhead of `new` and you don't need lots of it. Making the code bulletproof could also make it slow. By all means, criticize the code, if it is bad.

Comment: @user1095108: Seriously. The standard memory management routines have been optimized for specifically this type of allocation. But they are general purpose allocator so you can not expect optimal in all situations. Have you done any timing to see the performance differences?

Comment: @user1095108: The normal way to do this is to write an allocator (see std::allocator). This will help you do it properly. Then you can do things like a general purpose pool allocator etc..

Comment: @LokiAstari Hmmm, you write an allocator only if you want to expose your allocation mechanism to the `STL` and the like, otherwise you don't need to. And yeah, the code works for me, it's fast, and thread-safe. One could also write a `::std::allocator` adapter class that would call `static_new` and `static_delete`, but I don't really need this functionality.

Comment: Still don't understand the code. Comment it a bit more than I will review it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I still have trouble understanding how the whole works, but there are still some small things that could be improved:

- In your comments, you say that `A` is an integer type used as a bitmask. The safest [bitmask types](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/BitmaskType) are `unsigned` types or `std::bitset`. You should make this condition clear in your code, write

  ```
    template <typename T, typename BitmaskType=unsigned>
    struct static_store { /* ... */ };
  ```

  You could even make it an error to use a nonconforming type and create a `is_bitmask` trait, which would allow you to create a meaningful error message:

  ```
  static_assert(is_bitmask<BitmaskType>::value,
                "the BitmaskType requirements are not satisfied");
  ```
- I got confused with these lines:

  ```
  template <typename T, typename ...A>
  inline T* static_new(A&& ...args)
  ```

  It is once again a naming problem: I had in mind the template parameter `A` from `static_store`. Since it represents arguments to be forwarding, you should just use the common convetion and name it `Args` instead. I don't know whether there are written guidelines to name variadic parameter packs, but `Args` is probably the name that I saw the most often.
- You could probably slightly hide details and reduce the visual burden by using a `typedef` for the type of `store_`:

  ```
  using store_type = typename ::std::aligned_storage<sizeof(T), alignof(T)>::type;
  ```

Comment: `new` has to be fast, that's why no `::std::bitset`.

Comment: @user1095108 That makes sense :)